# nginx ALPN with debian 9 (stretch)

Tags: nginx, debian, http2, alpn

I just upgraded to Debian 9 (stretch) but system seems to not support ALPN negociation (after running a [HTTP2 test](https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test)). All guides over the internet still refers to Jessie (Debian 8) but none talks about Stretch (Debian 9).

```
OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.13.1
```

`nginx` was installed from official repository

[image]

Is there a simple way (without recompiling manually nginx) to get ALPN with Debian 9 & nginx ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**It's supported out of the box with Debian 9.**

My nginx vhost rollback at a version without the http2 statement.

Putting back the `listen 443 ssl http2` statement and checking with HTTP2 test confirms that it works nicely out of the box.

http://devops-life.com/blog/2017/06/27/nginx-alpn-debian-9-stretch.html